# How to say you did two things, but separately?

Tags: word-choice

When describing an experiment (inside a thesis paper), I want to explain that we took a sample and did two things to it, but not together, rather as two separate experiments.

One way to write it is :

> We took the sample and either did X to it, or did Y to it.

Another way is:

> We took the sample and did X to it, and separately did Y to it.

Frankly I'm not happy with either forms. What's a good way to write this?

Comment: If you would be more precise as to what X and Y are, it would be better (as the answer depends on what actions X and Y are).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sample taking is pretty much assumed, so no need to emphasize that at the start of your sentence. How about something like: "Samples were subjected to [Kjeldahl analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kjeldahl_method) or [Multiplex polymerase chain reaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplex-PCR) followed by [capillary electrophoresis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capillary_electrophoresis)"?

Comment: This seems like a sensible approach. OP has tied himself up in knots by starting with ***a** sample* - which makes it awkward to say what was done next, since different things were done with different parts of the sample. Just call them *samples* right from the start.

Comment: ...with a comma after "analysis", if the capillary electrophoresis was done only on those subjected to Multiplex polymerase chain reaction...otherwise, a comma after "reaction" would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

> We did X to the sample in one experiment and Y to it in another.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear from the example sentences how the sample was treated.  One might more clearly say something like the following:

> We did X to the sample, and then did Y to that result.
>   We did X to part of the sample, and Y to another part.
>   Separate portions of a sample were given treatment X or treatment Y.

You could prefix "After taking the sample," or "A sample was taken and" to the above if for some reason you wish to emphasize that a sample was taken, but otherwise could leave the sample-taking as an implied fact.